# array is not working as reference type ,do array come under reference data types in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, primitive

```
let names = ['mdv','venkatesh','nani']

// array methhods join 

let result = names.join('-');

console.log(result); o/p  mdv-venkatesh-nani
console.log(names);  o/p  ['mdv','venkatesh','nani']
```

I heard that array are the reference data types in JavaScript correct me if I am wrong.

I have changed the array using the `join` method why is it showing to the old reference?

Why do the changes not effect names array?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking please can you clarify?  If you need clarification on anything go to w3schools.com

Comment: [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) doesn't change (mutate) the array, it generates a string using the array's elements.

Comment: @SPlatten MDN is almost *always* a better JS resource than w3.

Answer (score 1):

Some methods change the reference array and others just return the value of the change.

Join is a method that only returns the changed array without changing it.

I suggest that when using some function, read its documentation to understand these details.

Join documentation on W3Schools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Answer (score 0):

The array method `join` ([MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)) does not change the original array, it returns a string. Other methods do change the original array, such as `push` ([MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)) or `shift` ([MDN ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)).

But you are correct, arrays are references. For example, consider this snippet. Try to think what the result will be before running it.

```js
var arr1 = "john".split('');
var arr2 = arr1.reverse();
var arr3 = "jones".split('');
arr2.push(arr3);
console.log("array 1: length=" + arr1.length + " last=" + arr1.slice(-1));
console.log("array 2: length=" + arr2.length + " last=" + arr2.slice(-1));
```

I got the snippet from [this site](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/interview-questions#question-29). Here is the explanation:

> The `reverse()` method returns a reference to the array itself (i.e., in this case, `arr1`). As a result, `arr2` is simply a reference to (rather than a copy of) `arr1`. Therefore, when anything is done to `arr2` (i.e., when we invoke `arr2.push(arr3);`), `arr1` will be affected as well since `arr1` and `arr2` are simply references to the same object.